# MVC refresh table data in modal using entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

good day. how can I refresh a modal table data? well, I have this textbox that when a user clicks show a modal pop-up. inside the pop-up is a partial view with the table and a search. When a user searches, instead of reloading the value in the modal, it redirects me to the partial view itself. I have seen a lot of examples like this one -- https://forums.asp.net/t/2098629.aspx?Advance+search+in+a+MVC+Popup+Window+ -- but still cannot go through it. its basically a modal popup but contains a partial view in it, once the search was clicked, just need to reload the table and no more. thanks in advance

Partial View Code:

```
    public ActionResult ShowTaxPayer(int? page, string searchString)
    {
        var user = (from u in db2.Payers
                    select new Taxpayer
                    {
                        ID = u.objid,
                        Firstname = u.firstname,
                        Lastname = u.lastname,
                        Middlename = u.middlename,
                        Address = u.primaryaddress
                    });

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
           return View(user.ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10));

        }
        else
        {
            return View(user.Where(s => s.Firstname.Contains(searchString)).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10));
        }
    }
```

Razor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Wizard", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)
<fieldset>
    <div class="wizard-step">

        @Html.Label("Taxpayer Name")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.taxpayername, new { data_toggle = "modal", data_target = "#myModal", data_backdrop = "static", data_keyboard = "false" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.taxpayername)

    </div>

    <div class="wizard-step">

        @Html.Label("Taxpayer Address")
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.taxpayeraddress)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.taxpayeraddress)

    </div>

    <div class="wizard-step">

        @Html.Label("Trade Name")
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.tradename)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.tradename)
    </div>

    <div class="wizard-step confirm">

    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="button" id="back-step" name="back-step" value="<-- Back" />
        <input type="button" id="next-step" name="next-step" value="Next -->" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}
```

The Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @{Html.RenderAction("ShowTaxPayer", "Wizard");}

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just need to load the data from my model in the modal and not redirect me to the actual view. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the javascript function to call the model.

Comment: i didnt use any javascript sr.

Comment: Actually, you load the data when the page loads. But you want to refresh the table. So, you need to use javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Here the Model Popup

```
<div class="modal-body">
@{Html.RenderAction("ShowTaxPayer", "Wizard");}
</div>
```

and changed to

```
  <div class="modal-body" id="popupTableName">

  </div>
```

and Add Javascript

```
     <script>
        window.onload = LoadTable();

        function LoadTable(){
             $.get( '@Url.Action("actionName","ControllerName", new { id = Model.ID } )', function(data) {
        $('#popupTableName').html(data);
    }); 
        }

function onChange(){
LoadTable();
}
        </script>
```

Comment: still getting thrown to the partial view itself. is it because of the address i made at the controller?